# Setting setOnQueryTextListener for SearchView gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, menu, searchview

I have Search View in the action bar as an option menu

in`onCreateOptionsMenu` method I get the search view as follow

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.serach).getActionView();
```

When I try to set `setOnQueryTextListener` it gives me null pointer exception.

my code is as follow

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

when i remove the listener it works fine.
can someone tell what I am doing wrong.

logcat log

```
    02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.example.test.PM_Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(PM_Fragment.java:61)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1865)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1919)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2552)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:479)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:845)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
02-11 20:04:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(27028):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: Maybe you can post the LogCat info.

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: What is on line 61 of `PM_Fragment`?

Comment: @Emmanuel : how did u formatted the log??

Comment: @SAIR I selected the logcat lines and pressed the `{}` that appears when you edit.

Comment: @Emmanuel : thumbs up (Y) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I could be so dumb.

i got the search view in`searchView` and i am setting listener for `mSearchView`. This is total my mistake